# Convert SQL Query to PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

What am I doing wrong here? I want this SQL query to execute inside a procedure FOR `i` columns. Am I doing the concatenation wrong? Thank you!

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..NR_COLUMNS
LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from (
    select id, c, row_number() over (partition by id 
        order by id, decode(mod(id, 2), 1, c, -c)) rn
      from FIRST_TABLE unpivot (c for col in (col'||i||' )))
  pivot (max(c) for rn in (i as col'||i||' ))';
END LOOP;
```

Errors: ORA-56901: non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values
ORA-06512: at line 4
56901. 0000 -  "non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values"
*Cause:    Attempted to use non-constant expression for pivot|unpivot values.
*Action:   Use constants for pivot|unpivot values.

Comment: Please provide some details on the issues or errors you're running into to help understand the issue.

Comment: @Drenmi I updated the code. Take a look please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert query from SQL to PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688456/convert-query-from-sql-to-pl-sql)

Comment: Have you tried to run just your select statement for test? I think the problem is in the select statement itself, not at the fact that you try to run it dynamically with the use of PL/SQL.

Comment: @user272735 It is also my question

Comment: Why did you as the same question again, and with less information? You should have added the requested error message to your original question, not started a new one.

Comment: @AlexPoole I didn't get any answer and I thought I had not asked the right question, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for instance. At first create empty table with same columns as your table.

```
create table sorted as select * from first_table where 1=0;
```

Now you can run this code block (you can put it in procedure or something). 
It fills table `sorted` with values ordered as you wanted.

```
declare
  v_list1 varchar2(32000); v_list2 varchar2(32000);
  v_sql varchar2(32000); v_num number; v_rec first_table%rowtype; 
begin

  select count(1) into v_num from user_tab_cols 
    where table_name = 'FIRST_TABLE';

  for i in 1..v_num-1 loop
    v_list1 := v_list1||'col'||i||', ';
    v_list2 := v_list2||i||', ';
  end loop;

  v_sql := 'select * from (
      select id, c, row_number() over (partition by id 
          order by id, decode(mod(id, 2), 1, c, -c)) rn
        from first_table unpivot (c for col in ('||rtrim(v_list1, ', ')||')))
    pivot (max(c) for rn in ('||rtrim(v_list2, ', ')||'))';

  for r in (select * from first_table) loop
    execute immediate v_sql||' where id = '||r.id into v_rec;
    insert into sorted values v_rec;
  end loop;
end;
```

---

And here is block which does not use other table, sorted data are collected 
in variable v_coll, then old data are removed from first_table and new inserted.

```
declare
  v_list varchar2(32000); v_sql varchar2(32000); v_num number;  
  type tft is table of first_table%rowtype;
  v_coll tft; -- variable for sorted data collection
begin

  select count(1) into v_num from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'FIRST_TABLE';

  for i in 1..v_num-1 loop
    v_sql := v_sql||'col'||i||', ';
    v_list := v_list||i||', ';
  end loop;

  v_sql := 'select * from (
      select id, c, row_number() over (partition by id 
          order by id, decode(mod(id, 2), 1, c, -c)) rn
        from first_table unpivot (c for col in ('||rtrim(v_sql, ', ')||')))
    pivot (max(c) for rn in ('||rtrim(v_list, ', ')||'))';

  -- execute statement and collect sorted data in v_coll
  execute immediate v_sql bulk collect into v_coll;

  delete from first_table;
  forall i in 1..v_coll.count 
    insert into first_table values v_coll(i);

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that you're referring to `i` as a variable inside the dynamic statement, where it is not in scope:

```
  pivot (max(c) for rn in (i as col'||i||' ))';
                           ^
```

You need to concatenate that as you have for the later reference:

```
  pivot (max(c) for rn in ('||i||' as col'||i||' ))';
```

That will now compile, but as @jva mentioned you are not selecting into anything so nothing happens with the results (and in fact [the query isn't actually executed](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS1201)). It isn't obvious what you want to do with them though.

It looks like you're trying to build up the pivot/unpivot clauses, rather than what you are actually doing, which is trying to run the query multiple unrelated times. I think this might be closer to what you're trying to achieve:

```
DECLARE
  NR_COLUMNS NUMBER := 2;
  QUERY VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  QUERY := 'select * from (
    select id, c, row_number() over (partition by id 
        order by id, decode(mod(id, 2), 1, c, -c)) rn
      from FIRST_TABLE unpivot (c for col in (';

  FOR i IN 1..NR_COLUMNS
  LOOP
    IF i > 1 THEN
      QUERY := QUERY || ', ';
    END IF;
    QUERY := QUERY || 'col' ||i;
  END LOOP;

  QUERY := QUERY || ')))
    pivot (max(c) for rn in (';

  FOR i IN 1..NR_COLUMNS
  LOOP
    IF i > 1 THEN
      QUERY := QUERY || ', ';
    END IF;
    QUERY := QUERY || i ||' as col' ||i;
  END LOOP;
  QUERY := QUERY || '))';

  -- just to debug what you're trying to run
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(QUERY);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE QUERY;
END;
/
```

The DBMS_OUTPUT shows a query generated like:

```
select * from (
    select id, c, row_number() over (partition by id 
        order by id, decode(mod(id, 2), 1, c, -c)) rn
      from FIRST_TABLE unpivot (c for col in (col1, col2)))
    pivot (max(c) for rn in (1 as col1, 2 as col2))
```

But it still won't actually do anything. You need to select into something (a collection), or open a cursor using that generated query and iterate over the results, or return a ref cursor, or something. It isn't clear what you want to happen.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.
All I want to do is to update the existing table with ordered results but I'm struggling so much for this.